# Rails: adding vendor/cache to SCM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Page 239 of [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) instructs us to add the `vendor/cache` directory to git.

Is this actually recommended practice? I was under the impression that this directory was platform-specific. Will it cause problems to commit a cache dir under OSX and then deploy to prod under Linux?

Comment: Typically you should not be including caches in your SCM. Cached data and other generated output like log files should never be ignored by Git.

Comment: \***Should be ignored**, sorry. I started typing "should never be tracked by Git" and tried to change it to "should be ignored by Git". Apologies if that created confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is where your app's gems are stored if you package them locally. So if you deploy from the SCM source and you want to use the exact gem packages that you are using locally, you'll need these files, which is why I suspect the book suggests this.

As far as the gem files go, it won't cause a problem if you develop on a Mac and deploy to a Linux server.

Comment: To clarify- as the name implies, it's a cache for the downloaded (yet un-expanded) gemfiles.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - yes.

Long answer - it's very handy to keep your gem dependencies with your application. Not just a Gemfile and Gemfile.lock but also the gems themselves.

There are numerous advantages - such as having all your gems available without having to connect to a gem server.